# 404 error when looking for page on Django site

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to create a media page on my site through **Django**. I'm following a course and I'm pretty stumped. I'm following exactly what the guy is doing but I keep getting the following error:

**Error:**

Page not found (404)

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

**My settings.py:**

`MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'media'`
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

**urls.py:**

`from django.contrib import admin`
`from django.urls import path`
`from django.conf import settings`
`from django.conf.urls.static import static`

`urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls),`

`] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

The problem arises as soon as I enter this line:

`+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

I haven't written anything in the views.py folders yet because the course hasn't required me to on this project so far.

I'm just a newbie so I don't really have any clue what's happening when the code looks correct but I'm still running into the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is path for displaying the index page i think you are missing `path('/', views.your_view, name="your_view")`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your site has these 2 address available for access.

```
admin/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

However, you are requesting for http://127.0.0.1:8000/ instead.
Maybe try http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image.jpg for exmaple.